# Align two inline-blocks next to another inline-block

Tags: html, css

I want to align two inline-blocks next to another inline-block so that there is a big square and two smaller squares that are on its right. The two little squares should make a column, and this column should be next to the big square.

So I firstly added the big square, with a float:left and the first little square. Then I thought that when I add the last square, it will put it below the first little square. But no, it put it to the right of the first little square.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BMYHw/2/ and the code:

HTML

```
<div id="i1"></div>
<div id="i2"></div>
<div id="i3"></div>
```

CSS

```
#i1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#i2 {
    background-color: green;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#i3 {
    background-color: red;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So all I want is that the red square in the example goes just below the green one and stick to the blue one. Thanks!

EDIT: Problem solved, thank you everyone for your really quick answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:table;` property to achieve this.

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BMYHw/7/)

**The Code:**

```
#i2 {
    background-color: green;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    display: table;
}
```

This solves your purpose of ..

> I want is that the red square in the example goes just below the green
>   one and stick to the blue one.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Thank you, it worked as expected! And I didn't want to use container because I had other blocks floating around, and it would have messed my stuff. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/BMYHw/6/
you need an extra container to hold them. floatting or inline-block

```
.hold {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put the two small squares inside a new container. ie.

`<div id="container>
  <!--the two small squares-->
</div>`

sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/BMYHw/9/)